# Get an image of google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mapkit

I'm trying to get a snapshot of a piece of google maps. However, mapkit doesn't appear to have a similar function. Is there a way to get an image file of a part of google maps without breaking Google's agreement?

P.S. Taking a screenshot of the iphone is not an option, as it is possible i need a snapshot of a part that's mostly out of screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use static maps API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/